# Masterpass make redirect occur in iframe or prevent navigation

Tags: javascript, html, mastercard

I am attempting to integrate masterpass into an existing .net application. I have followed their [documentation](https://developer.mastercard.com/documentation/masterpass-merchant-integration-v7#express-checkout) but i would like instead of clicking on the masterpass button and being redirected to their sign in page for authentication that their login page open in either a popup or an iframe so that the user is not forced to leave my checkout page. Has anyone had any luck with this? Their page states that express checkout which is essentially what i am looking for is not available in the US or Canada. Has anyone found a work around? 
My code looks like this

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#clickMe').click(function () {
            
masterpass.checkout({
“checkoutId”:”my checkoutId”,
“allowedCardTypes”:[“amex”,”visa”, “etc”],
“amount”:”30.00”
“currency”:”USD”
});
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://sandbox.masterpass.com/integration/merchant.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   
<div>
            My Form
         
             <img alt="Checkout with Masterpass" role="button" src="https://static.masterpass.com/dyn/img/btn/global/mp_chk_btn_147x034px.svg" id="clickMe"/>
              
        </div>
```

Comment: Opening it in an iframe would be outright idi*tic - users would have no address bar to verify that they are indeed entering their credentials on a genuine page of that service, and not a phishing clone you or someone else set up …

Comment: @CBroe thanks for the soy advice. Have you found a solution to this yourself?

Comment: Redirecting to the payment service and then back from there to your shop page is a very common practice. People are probably used to exactly this already. Plus, it eliminates problems such as, payment service already called in a new tab, wants me to pay amount X … now I go back to my first tab with your shop in it, and change my shopping cart contents … oops. I think you are trying to solve a problem here that doesn’t need solving in the first place. The best and most reliable solution has already been established …

Comment: Ok, thats a response i can live with.